# How to add single static item to ListView

Tags: android, listview

I have `SherlockListActivity` and I fill the `ListView` with specific items. I use my own `Adapter` for it.

But in one situation I have to fill my `ListView` with just one item which is specified in `single_list_item.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="top" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="top"
            android:text="@string/singleItem1"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="top"
            android:text="@string/singleItem2"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

How can I achieve that? Do I need to use an Adapter here? If so, which is the best for this situation?

Comment: This depends on where you want to insert this information and what type of `Adapter` you're using.

Comment: I want to insert this item via function, after button being clicked.

Answer (score 0):

Use Header/Footer views for this list view.